# How can I import multiple taxonomy terms using Feeds and the Feeds XML Parser

Tags: feeds

Currently the xml feed looks something like this

```
<hotel>
    <hotel_facilities>
        <facility>Gym</facility>
        <facility>Restaurant</facility>
        <facility>Bar</facility>
    </hotel_facilities>
...
</hotel>
```

I've trying to import all the facilities as taxonomy terms using the [Feeds XPath Parser](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) but I am only able to import a single facility. I'm not sure if the module supports this. What currently happens when I set the context to hotel and the xpath query as hotel_facilities/facility it results in the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'Restaurant', 'Bar'' at line 1

If I use the query: `hotel_facilities/facility[1]` it returns and inputs the term into my taxonomy vocabulary, but I require all the terms to be added.

Is there a query/module or setting that I need to run; or is this a limitation of the Feeds/Feeds XPath Parser parser modules?

Answer (score 1):

[Feeds Tamper](http://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) will sort this out (I know this for a fact, as I've done this in the last week).

Set your query to `hotel_facilities/facility` which will return a comma separated list of facilities (you won't see this array as you'll be exploding it. Feel free to `dpm()` it though). Using Feeds Tamper, you can explode this array.

Go to your feed, and there will be a "Tamper" menu item at the top. If you click this, and then go down whatever xpathparser if importing these facilities. Then click *Add plugin* and find the explode plugin (you can find it under *List*)

[image: Feeds tamper add plugin UI]

Don't forget to set your Feeds mapping to *Search taxonomy terms by: **Term Name*** and check the "Auto create" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the base path to /hotel/hotel_facilites/facility

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Chapabu has the right answer.  I went a step further and made a Tamper plugin.

When I needed to set this up myself, I ended up having to add 3 filters to make it work (remove the xml tags, trim content, & drop empty elements).  Since I have ~8 similar fields that would all need the same filters, I just wrote up a simple filter for Tamper that does this for me:

Copy this code and add it to `sites/all/modules/contrib/feeds_tamper/plugins/xml_explode.inc`.  You can then select it from from the list of Tamper plugins.  Read the notes on this filter for help.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Return an array of text from a set of XML nodes.
 */

$plugin = array(
  'form' => 'feeds_tamper_xml_explode_form',
  'callback' => 'feeds_tamper_xml_explode_callback',
  'validate' => 'feeds_tamper_xml_explode_validate',
  'name' => 'Explode XML',
  'multi' => 'direct',
  'category' => 'List',
);

function feeds_tamper_xml_explode_form($importer, $element_key, $settings) {
  $form = array();
  $form['info'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('In order for this to work, make sure you do these things:'
      . '<ul>'
      . '  <li>Write your xpath value to the parent followed by "\*" (eg <code>"Grandparent\Parent\*"</code>)</li>'
      . '  <li>Parse this node as "raw" xml (See <a href="http://goo.gl/cTv6Sc">http://goo.gl/cTv6Sc</a>)</li>'
      . '  <li>Make sure the xml node is only one level deep.</li>'
      . '</ul>'
      . '<b>Note</b>: This plugin is not intended for production.'),
  );
  return $form;
}

function feeds_tamper_xml_explode_callback($result, $item_key, $element_key, &$field, $settings, $source) {
  $out = array();

  if(is_array($field)){
    foreach($field as $k => $string){
      $subject = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
      $out[] = trim( (string)$subject );
    }
  }

  $field = $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a way to achieve a goal very similar to this. Refer [my post here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159434/how-to-import-multiple-terms-from-xml-into-a-node/159482#answer-159482) if someone else finds a solution for this.