# How to import multiple terms from XML into a node?

Tags: 7, feeds

I am trying to import all the Destinations as taxonomy terms using following XML. In my situation, the list is not a comma separated list. It is as follows:

```
<product>
    <category>Ship</category>
    <id>000032</id>
    <Description>The description comes here</Description>
    <list>
        <Destination>
            <DestinationName>Dest 1</DestinationName>
            <DestinationCountryISOAlpha3>US</DestinationCountryISOAlpha3>
        </Destination>
        <Destination>
            <DestinationName>Dest 2</DestinationName>
            <DestinationCountryISOAlpha3/>
        </Destination>
    <list>
</product>
```

I have a taxonomy called destinations and the list is already imported. Now how can I import Destinations list of a product as a term reference for the product node. I am using feed module, Feeds XPath Parser, and Feeds Tamper modules?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to achieve this goal at least for my use case. Publish my solution here for anyone to use if required.

My Settings for XPath XML parser :

```
Context -> //product/list/Destination
Product id -> ../../id
List of ports -> DestinationName # This is a term reference field which well have multiple terms per product
```

Then mapped all required fields as normal.

I created a small module with `hook_feeds_after_parse()` hook (I will use "My module").

My module has one `.info` file and the `.module` file.

```
function my_module_feeds_after_parse(FeedsSource $source, FeedsParserResult $result) {
    $current_id = -1;
    $cuurent_destination_list_final = '';
    foreach($result->items as $key => $row) {
        if($current_id !== $row['xpathparser:0']){
            $cuurent_destination_list_final = '';
            $current_id = $row['xpathparser:0'];
        }
        if($cuurent_destination_list_final === ''){
            $cuurent_destination_list_final = $row['xpathparser:1'];
        }else{
            $cuurent_destination_list_final = $cuurent_destination_list_final . ',' . $row['xpathparser:1'];
        }
        $result->items[$key]['destination_list_final'] = $cuurent_destination_list_final;
    }
}
```

What this module does is it creates a comma separated list of destinations.
Once we set $result->items[$key]['destination_list_final'] (This builds a comma separated list of terms) using this module, we can refer destination_list_final from Feeds Tamper (Refer [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1360518)).

Install and enable [Feeds Tamper PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper_php). 
Add 3 pluggings to `xpathparser:1 -> List of Destinations`

1. Execute php code (This come from above installed module) -> `return     $item['destination_list_final'];`
2. Find replace - Use to remove double quotes (`"`)
3. Explode - Use to explode the comma separated list we created from the custom module.

That's it. It worked for me.